# Find recently created directory in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, ctime

I have a list of folders in a path. I want to get the most recently created folders/files in the path in Node js.

code :

```
fs.readdir(path,function(err,files){
console.log("files in the path",files);
}
```

from the list of files i want the most recently created

Comment: share us the code, what you have tried so far. you can get the latest created folder by checking the date of the folder.

Comment: how to get the date and time and get the only the latest files

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696218/get-the-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-node-js I hope you will get some help from here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fs.statSync(path)` to check for file updatetime.

```
fs.readdir(path,function(err,files){
 files.filter(file => {
const stats = fs.statSync(path)
  return someSpecificDate < stats.mtime
});
})
```

Comment: The files get created each few seconds so i wanted to find the last created files in the directory

Comment: @yamuna You may better off using https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar if files are added every few seconds . You can watch folder and it can report all the changes in directory

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');

var directory = './';

fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
    if(err) {
        // handle error; e.g., folder didn't exist
    }
    // files refer to array of files in directory iterate through every file and refer the below link for file info operation

      https://code-maven.com/system-information-about-a-file-or-directory-in-nodejs
    for getting file/dir information 
});
```

Comment: we can get the file ctime and mtime but how to get the recent files among 100 files

Comment: create an array of object with file name and timestamp then use some sort technique to sort with time then pick it up your deserved item.

Answer (score 0):

`fs` has a `stat` function which takes a `path` and returns a `stats` object contains the last accessed, modified and created timestamps.

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

Example usage here: https://code-maven.com/system-information-about-a-file-or-directory-in-nodejs

You could access each paths 'stats', add the created timestamps into an array with the path and then sort the array by timestamp descending.

Something like:

```
const paths = [
  '/path/to/file1',
  '/path/to/file2',
  '/path/to/file3',
  '/path/to/file4',
]

let pathTimestamps = []

// Add path timestamps to the pathTimestamps array as an object containing the path and created timestamp
paths.forEach(path => {
  fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
    pathTimestamps.push({ path: path, createdTimestamp: stats.birthtimeMs })
  }
})

// Sort the array by timestamp descending (newest paths first)
pathTimestamps.sort(a, b => {
  b.createdTimestamp - a.createdTimestamp
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fs.stat(path/of/the/file)`.
It returns the following information:

```
Stats {
  dev: 2114,
  ino: 48064969,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 85,
  gid: 100,
  rdev: 0,
  size: 527,
  blksize: 4096,
  blocks: 8,
  atimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  mtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  ctimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  birthtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  atime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  mtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  ctime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  birthtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT
 }
```

You should check the value `mtime` because it represents the "Modified Time" or Time when file data last modified. It is changed by the following commands: mknod, utimes and write system calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
return _.max(files, function (f) {
  var fullpath = path.join(dir, f);
  return fs.statSync(fullpath).ctime;
});
```

The above code worked for me calling this function to get the recent file